# Proving the set $\left\lbrace \frac{(x + y)^2}{\sqrt{y}} \leq x - y + 5, y > 0 \right\rbrace$ is convex

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, convex-analysis

I have recently picked up a course on Convex Analysis in my spare time, but feel I'm not quite up to speed with the 'tricks' for proving a set is convex.

I have managed to prove this by moving all terms involving $x$ and $y$ to one side, then brute force computing the Hessian and showing it's positive definite, then concluding that the sub-level set of a convex function is convex. But is there a neater way of showing this using some of the 'tricks' shown, for example, in [Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook)?

For reference, here is a plot from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3E0%2C%20%28x%2By%29%5E2%2Fsqrt%5By%5D%3Cx-y%2B5):

[image]

Comment: Did this set arise in some particular context? The context may be helpful for your question.

Comment: This was in the context of using Disciplined Convex Programming (DCP, https://dcp.stanford.edu/), in particular putting expressions in a form that can be accepted by this software (and as a bonus some practice proving trickier sets are convex, but this one I had no clever ideas beyond brute force).

Comment: A formal point: the set in the title is not well-defined. I guess, it should have the form: $\ \{(x\ y): \ldots\},\ $ where "$\ldots$" are as in the title, inside the title's braces.

Answer (score 5):

The constraints can be reformulated as linear matrix inequalities (LMIs). In the book ["Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), LMI first shows up in the Example 2.10. Please see the following:

First, reformulate the constraint $\frac{(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{y}} \leq x - y + 5$ as a matrix inequality. Moving everything to one side, we have $x - y + 5 - \frac{(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{y}} \geq 0$. Follow Appendix A.5.5 in [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) and define $A:=\sqrt{y}, B:=(x+y), C:=x-y+5$, we have the original inequality as $S:=C - B^\top A^{-1}B \geq 0$. Note that $A=\sqrt{y} > 0$ as $y>0$. Observe that $S$ is actually the Schur complement of $A$ in $X$ defined in the following:
$$X:=\begin{bmatrix} x-y+5 & x+y \\ x+y & \sqrt{y} \end{bmatrix}.$$
With the [condition for positive definiteness of Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness), the following is true:
$$ A > 0, S > 0 \Leftrightarrow X \succ 0 \tag{1}.$$
Hence, the first constraint with fraction can be rewritten as the matrix inequality $X\succ 0$.

Second, we introduce a slack variable $s$ and reform LMI (1) as the following constraints:
$$\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix} x-y+5 & x+y \\ x+y & s \end{bmatrix} \succ 0 \tag{2} \\
\sqrt{y} > s > 0 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
Lastly, taking square of the first part of inequality (3) on both side and appy Schur complement again to get the following LMI:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} y & s \\ s & 1 \end{bmatrix} > 0 \tag{4}
$$

With the above three steps, you can represent the set in your problem as the set described by LMI (2) and (4). Since the LMI are affine in all decision variables, the set is convex.

Comment: Thank you but it look a little bit unatural for me. How can we go from the original consraint directly to an LMI ? is there a pattern ?
Also does a second order cone constraint transformation possible in this case ? or do LMI is the only way ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've edited the answer above to include more details on the Schur complement step. I don't have a very compelling answer on how to do this kind of trick, but I would try the Schur complement trick if I see something being a fraction with the numerator being a square. 

For the second-order cone (SOC), I'm not sure whether you can formulate this problem in SOC. Maybe it is possible by introducing some other slack variables. One thing to note is that an SOC can always be formulated as an LMI. You can check the V&B book or the wiki of SOC to see the details.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I added an answer with an SOCP reformulation.

Answer (score 2):

You can reformulate as SOCP by introducing four variables $z_i$ and the following constraints:
\begin{align}
z_1 &\ge 0 \\
z_2 &\ge 0 \\
z_3 &= 0.5\\
x - y - 2 z_2 &\ge -5\\
2y z_3 &\ge z_1^2\\
2z_2 z_1 &\ge z_4^2\\
x + y - z_4 &= 0
\end{align}

---

By request, here is the SAS code I used:

```
proc optmodel;
   var x;
   var y >= 0;
   con (x+y)^2/sqrt(y) <= x - y + 5;
   expand / conic;
quit;
```

The output is:

```
Var x                                                                                             
Var y >= 0                                                                                        
Var _ADDED_VAR_[1] >= 0                                                                           
Var _ADDED_VAR_[2] >= 0                                                                           
Fix _ADDED_VAR_[3] = 0.5                                                                          
Var _ADDED_VAR_[4]                                                                                
Constraint _ACON_[1]: - x + y + 2*_ADDED_VAR_[2] <= 5                                             
Constraint _ADDED_CON_[1]: RSOC(y, _ADDED_VAR_[3], _ADDED_VAR_[1])                                
Constraint _ADDED_CON_[2]: RSOC(_ADDED_VAR_[2], _ADDED_VAR_[1], _ADDED_VAR_[4])                   
Constraint _ADDED_CON_[3]: - _ADDED_VAR_[4] + x + y = 0
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more about how to formulate this SOCP? It seems like you arrive at this by introducing a few variables to replace the complex terms. But I couldn't come up with it. I would love to learn how to do this reformulation!

Comment: @Shih-ChiLiao The transformation to SOCP is automated in SAS: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_040/casmopt/casmopt_optmodel_details63.htm  The techniques are described in Erickson, J., and Fourer, R. (2019). Detection and Transformation of Second-Order Cone Programming Problems in a General-Purpose Algebraic Modeling Language. Technical report, Department of Industrial Engineering and Management Sciences, Northwestern University. https://optimization-online.org/?p=15791.

Comment: @RobPratt  I am sorry but can you demonstrate us on how to do that ? Particularly, what kind of input did you enter into the SAS software and how to interpret the output ? The document is not really clear on the RSOC , SOC stuff

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I added the SAS code and output to my answer.  My $z_i$ corresponds to _ADDED_VAR_[i] in the output.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you so much for sharing the details. This is such a powerful tool. I wonder if you are aware of any similar transformation to SDP as well?

Comment: @Shih-ChiLiao No SDP yet, but SAS also does automated linearization: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_040/casmopt/casmopt_optmodel_details57.htm

Comment: This is a bit strange, not sure why the variable $z_4$ does not require any non negativity assumtion ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh For SOCP constraints, only the variables that appear on the LHS are required to be nonnegative.

Comment: @Shih-ChiLiao does all optimization problem that involve polynomial objective function and polynomial constraints are SDP - presentable ?